# How do I get shared preference to save the background color when I swipe

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm learning about shared preferences and how to save the background color even when I close the app. I have it working when I press buttons to change colors but I'm also trying to save the color when I swipe left to brighten the color and left to darken the color. When I exit and open the app again, it's back to the color it was on the last button press and not swipe. What do I need to change to get that to save? Would I need to add a new listener to check for changes in the swipe?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("TurnToTech", "Project Name - SharedPreference");


        lib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(MainActivity.this,
                R.id.gestureOverlayView1);
        gesture = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestureOverlayView1);
        gesture.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

        radioColorGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioColor);
        radioColorGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            // Called when the checked state of a compound button has changed.
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int selectedId = radioColorGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radioColorButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);


                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(prefs_name,0);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                editor.putString("col",radioColorButton.getText().toString());

                editor.commit();
                setBackground();

            }
        });

        setBackground();


    } 

@Override
    protected  void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(prefs_name, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        editor.putString("col", CurrentColor);

        editor.apply();
        setBackground();
    }

 @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(prefs_name, 0);

        ArrayList<GestureStroke> strokeList = gesture.getStrokes();

        float f[] = strokeList.get(0).points;
        String str = "";

        if (f[0] < f[f.length - 2]) {
            str = "Right gesture";
        } else if (f[0] > f[f.length - 2]) {
            str = "Left gesture";
        } else {
            str = "no direction";
        }


        if(str =="Left gesture" && (CurrentColor == "Green" || CurrentColor == "Dark Green") ) {
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#19faa4"));
            CurrentColor = "Bright Green";
        }

        else if (str == "Right gesture" && (CurrentColor == "Green" || CurrentColor == "Bright Green")) {
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#004e37"));
            CurrentColor = "Dark Green";
        }

        else if(str =="Left gesture" && (CurrentColor == "Red" || CurrentColor == "Dark Red")) {
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f04242"));
            CurrentColor = "Bright Red";
        }

        else if (str == "Right gesture" && (CurrentColor == "Red" || CurrentColor == "Bright Red")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#84001b"));
            CurrentColor = "Dark Red";
        }

        else if(str =="Left gesture" && (CurrentColor == "Blue" || CurrentColor == "Dark Blue")) {
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#54dde9"));
            CurrentColor = "Bright Blue";
        }

        else if (str == "Right gesture" && (CurrentColor == "Blue" || CurrentColor == "Bright Blue")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000080"));
            CurrentColor = "Dark Blue";
        }

    }


    //change the background
    private void setBackground(){

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(prefs_name, 0);

        // Retrieve a String value from the preferences. default "Green"
        String color_pref = settings.getString("col", "Blue");

        // After retrieving change background color accordingly.
        if(color_pref.equals("Green")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#19a57c"));
            radioColorGroup.check(R.id.radioGreen);
            CurrentColor = "Green";
        }
        if(color_pref.equals("Red")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dd002e"));
            radioColorGroup.check(R.id.radioRed);
            CurrentColor = "Red";
        }
        if(color_pref.equals("Blue")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#325eff"));
            radioColorGroup.check(R.id.radioBlue);
            CurrentColor = "Blue";
        }

        if(color_pref.equals("Bright Green")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#19faa4"));
            radioColorGroup.check(R.id.radioGreen);
            CurrentColor = "Bright Green";
        }
        if(color_pref.equals("Bright Red")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f04242"));
            radioColorGroup.check(R.id.radioRed);
            CurrentColor = "Bright Red";
        }
        if(color_pref.equals("Bright Blue")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#54dde9"));
            radioColorGroup.check(R.id.radioBlue);
            CurrentColor = "Bright Blue";
        }

        if(color_pref.equals("Dark Green")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#004e37"));
            radioColorGroup.check(R.id.radioGreen);
            CurrentColor = "Dark Green";
        }
        if(color_pref.equals("Dark Red")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#84001b"));
            radioColorGroup.check(R.id.radioRed);
            CurrentColor = "Dark Red";
        }
        if(color_pref.equals("Dark Blue")){
            radioColorGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000080"));
            radioColorGroup.check(R.id.radioBlue);
            CurrentColor = "Dark Blue";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also post the code of your GesturePerformedListener?

Comment: @Zartha Just added the snippet for onGesturePerformed

Comment: also the function setBackground.

Comment: you are not saving the sharedPreferences in gesture. You just have to call the same as you do on checkedChangeListener. But if you just want to save the color at the last state before your app closes, you can do this in `onStop`. You could prevent too much work in the background.

Comment: You need to make a call to [`apply()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) or [`commit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) for the values to be saved. Personally, `apply()` is the better choice. You should really add this "save" feature to the main activity's [`onPause()`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onpause).

Comment: @Tigger I've added apply() to mainActivity's onPause. However, it's only saving for bright green and dark green. Any other color (blue and red) would not save. It'll only be the button defaults for those when I reopen the app.